# selecting dates from a table into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and one of the fields is a date field.

I have been asked to write a query that returns a list of distinct dates (ordered) in say column A and then have another column, say B of dates where the date in column B is the greatest date that is less than column A.

```
    MyDateField

    2017-01-01
    2017-01-01
    2017-01-01
    2017-01-02
    2017-01-02
    2017-01-03
    2017-01-04
    2017-01-05
    2017-01-05
    2017-01-05
```

Answer required

```
    2017-01-05      2017-01-04
    2017-01-04      2017-01-03
    2017-01-03      2017-01-02
    2017-01-02      2017-01-01
    2017-01-01
```

Comment: Does this column B also come from he same table, or just a `date_column - '1 day'` would do it?

Comment: it comes from the same table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using SQL-Server 2012+, then you can use `LAG()` to fetch the last biggest date out of the table:

```
SELECT t.date,
       LAG(t.date,1) OVER(ORDER BY t.date) as last_biggest_date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT s.dateField FROM YourTable s) t
```

Comment: Just noting that this is SQL Server 2012+, although he didn't post his DBMS.

Comment: that is brillant!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a CTE among other things. This gets a list of distinct dates, and then uses a self-join.

```
with cte as(
    select distinct 
        MyDateField
    from 
        YourTable)

select
    c.MyDateField
    ,max(c2.MyDateField) as MaxDate
from
    cte c
left join cte c2 on c2.MyDateField < c.MyDateField
group by
    c.MyDateField
order by
    c.MyDateField
```

**Or a simple self-join without a CTE**

```
--in this case DISTINCT isn't really needed, but left in case there are other columns   
select distinct 
    c.MyDateField
    ,max(c2.MyDateField) as MaxDate
from
    myTable c
left join myTable c2 on c2.MyDateField < c.MyDateField
group by
    c.MyDateField
order by
    c.MyDateField
```

Comment: You are correct @UsagiMiyamoto, I just find it easier to read for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply subquery to return smaller date in second column:

```
select distinct t1.MyDateField, x.MyDateField
from MyTable t1
outer apply (select max(MyDateField) MyDateField  
             from MyTable t2 
             where t1.MyDateField> t2.MyDateField) x
```

Comment: Just a heads up... the `TOP 1` the outer apply isn't guaranteed to be the one you want (or even the same each time), without specifying an `ORDER BY` in the same sub-query.

Comment: You are right, i switch `TOP 1` with `MAX()` so it always return correct date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d, LAG(d) OVER (ORDER BY d) AS d2
    FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT d 
                FROM (VALUES ('2017-01-01'),
                            ('2017-01-01'),
                            ('2017-01-01'),
                            ('2017-01-02'),
                            ('2017-01-02'),
                            ('2017-01-03'),
                            ('2017-01-04'),
                            ('2017-01-05'),
                            ('2017-01-05'),
                            ('2017-01-05')) AS dates(d)
        ) AS d(d)
ORDER BY d DESC;
```

Output:

```
d          d2
---------- ----------
2017-01-05 2017-01-04
2017-01-04 2017-01-03
2017-01-03 2017-01-02
2017-01-02 2017-01-01
2017-01-01 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as(
select 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by MyDateField) 'RN',
MyDateField from TempTable
group by MyDateField)
select t2.MyDateField,t1.MyDateField from CTE t1
right join CTE t2
on t1.RN=t2.RN-1
order by t2.MyDateField desc
```